# Web application [/payapplication] threw load() exceptionjava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jvnet.hk2.external.runtime.ServiceLocatorRuntimeBean

Tags: java, maven, runtime-error

I get always this Error:

```
Web application [/payapplication] threw load() exceptionjava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jvnet.hk2.external.runtime.ServiceLocatorRuntimeBean
```

I added this to my pom in my maven project:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
 <artifactId>hk2-locator</artifactId>
 <version>2.1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

but that didn't help anything and I'm not sure what to do with that kind of Error?

Comment: Did you verify that the jar is present in the application war ?

Comment: where can I verify that?

Comment: Open the generated War archive and navigate to youWar.war\WEB-INF\lib\ and check the presence of hk2-locator.

Comment: after adding the dependency to my pom I got now this error: `Servlet.service() for servlet [com.somepath.Application] in context with path [/payapplication] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/process/internal/RequestExecutorFactory] with root causejava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestExecutorFactory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version 2.1.9 don't exist in the central Maven repository [as you can see here.](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-locator)

**EDIT : Adding the new dependency**

CreatePolicy enum was added starting from the version 2.3.0. So you must add a new dependecy.

[hk2-locator 2.4.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-locator/2.4.0)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
    <artifactId>hk2-locator</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

[hk2-api 2.4.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-api/2.4.0)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
    <artifactId>hk2-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Well now I got this error: `StandardWrapper.Throwablejava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocatorFactory$CreatePolicy`

Comment: I edited the answer. You must add `hk2-api` dependency

Comment: Okay, the version you choosed was an old one. You must choose at least the version 2.3.0. I edited the post, it must work now.